# Click all Check boxes in C# Webdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I want to click all check boxes which is dynamically generated in C#, webdriver .Can somebody please tell me how to write a for loop for each checkboxes. In the inspect element , I have only the type and name of the element. Thanks Kalaivani

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on [ask]. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like, but the selector we're no able to write without the html code:

```
var checkboxes = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("selector that find all generated checkboxes"));
foreach(var checkbox in checkboxes)
{
    checkbox.Click();
}
```

Comment: You are probably going to need a slight pause between clicks.

Comment: Hello Striter, Thank you for the sample. I used Xpath and the below code worked for me.Once again I want to thank you for providing the for each loop as I was not able to get that answer when I searched for. List<IWebElement> checkbox = new List<IWebElement>();
            var checkboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            foreach (var check in checkboxes)
             { 
                check.Click();
             }

Comment: @Kalaivani your `checkbox` variable is probably not used, you can remove it safely. Also the threadsleep before the loop only is necessary if there is any ajax or javascript running that can affect the element display. If there is no one of these scripts, you can remove it too :)

Comment: @JeffC In Selenium, if the action to click in the checkbox has no any script that affect the others element display, is safe to click it without a pause or a wait is this kind of loop

Comment: Hi Striter, As you said , it worked without the Threadsleep. Thanks for the advice.